# Change WiFi networks Programatically

Tags: windows-iot, c#

Running a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT
Couple questions.

1. is there a way to stop the program from code to enter the boot screen?
2. Is there a way to join see and join wireless networks from code?

I wanted to add to add a way to my app to change WiFi networks if needed.

It can be done from the setup screen but how to get there from a touchscreen or be able to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the entire source code at the following link

https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp

The Dashboard is called the **DefaultApp**

I have a sneeky feeling that you find your destiny in this file [NetworkListControl.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp/IoTCoreDefaultApp/UserControls/NetworkListControl.xaml.cs)

by using the line

```
networks = new ObservableCollection<WiFiAvailableNetwork>(await networkPresenter.GetAvailableNetworks());
```

You need to download the source code, open it in Visual Studio and work out where the `NetworkPresenter` class is coming from.